# Webform generator?

Tags: asp.net, html, user-interface, webforms

just wondering is there any free tool which can aid in making the GUI/interface layout of asp.net/html forms ? My forms mostly end up in being less user friendly and not good looking at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using Bootstrap framework to get my design up to speed in no time. You can use this tool to get forms created in minutes. http://bootsnipp.com/forms?version=3

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try downloading the Firefox Web Developer Toolbar and use it to reverse-engineer some simple, good looking sites that you come across?

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/61772/

You can use it to grab the entire CSS of any site, or hover over areas of a page and see the various divs and their associated CSS rules highlighted.

Comment: seems like a nice idea for learning the actual stuff, however is there any tool to fasten up the process in designing webforms? I came across some but they were pay to use.

Comment: Did you try the new Webmatrix?